# Why does exporting to FBX in 3dmax loses simulated animation

Tags: animation, 3dsmax, simulations, export

I made a cloth simulation (wind blowing a cloth). When I export it to FXB and the animation box is ticked on export menu it seems ok (no error in longs). When I reload it to Unity. or 3DMAX again. The wind animation is lost. How can I fix that?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure, but I think that the wind is calculated differently differing on the engine. So unless it is a raw animation you will have to set it up again inside of Unity using the wind settings provided by Unity engine. With the 3D Studio Max. I have no idea what can be going on there

Comment: Thanks, I think I did not find a better solution (still searching)

Answer (score 1):

The wind is calculated differently differing on the engine. So unless it is a raw, baked animation you will have to set it up again inside of Unity using the wind settings provided by Unity engine. As for the 3D Studio Max. I have no idea what can be going on there.

Comment: Thanks, If the scripting work will not be the solution I may try this one as well.

Comment: To add a bit more elaboration onto this answer: usually (it depends on the file format I suppose) the only animation data that will be exported from your animation tool into an external file format are keyframes, so any other animation data will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

If ya wanna keep the wind sim you need to bake it http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/3ds-Max-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-F122A886-941D-4E40-822C-F57D90049BD5.htm,topicNumber=d30e269398

otherwise use unity to re-simulate it.
Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Sadly baking the simulation did not work It looked nice withouth forces. After the export I recived the model withouth the animation in the FBX file. The animation time is included, but nothing happens. (My primary model is a ghost /cloth dropped on an object with eyes and other features/ I tried to trick movement animation with the wind force effect) The cloth did not move nicely in 3dsmax and nothing in FBX (If I reloade it in 3dsmax or unity the animation is lost)

Comment: I guess theres 2 ways to go about this if its for pc I'd go this route http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-SkinnedCloth.html that way you dont need to worry about the cloth and blending it when it changes direction and what not. Now if its for the phone i would go with morph deformers/blend shapes that way you can bake that if for some reason the FBX isn't accepting the keys from the sim bake which is weird.

Comment: Thanks again (It will be phone) Yesterday I was reseaching more into the topic. I figured out that I can export with Point Cache file. (Damn 3ds max exports default to xml + mc but configuration can be made to convert it to pc2) This pc2 file with some scripting work found here [link] (http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/130564-Point-Cache-reader) we were able to import the vertex animation. It still looked like poor ghost had paralisis rather then flown on the wind. We will work on the script to make the import possible in the next 2 nights.If it is not working out we will probably buy MegaFiers

Comment: Actually we lost the fight and boutght MegaFiers. It was working perfectly. The support was more then nice! Thanks Chris! Megafiers did import all the needed data to Unity. I hope that is not a adertisment I will be banned for. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you read the conversation, you'll see that my helpers were right. But to handle the problem easily we bought an extension to Unity, which did what we needed. I'm sure that the problem can also be solved with the following methods:

- Workaround: Bone animation (Remake the whole thing with bones)
- Simulation in Unity: Use cloth simulation in Unity with Unity forces.

Or buy the stuff we did (Megafiers)... as we are lazy.